# when i make a function each li click inside click function then li click run in looping everytime. how to prevent looping click

Tags: javascript, html

Please first click on input and click on different diffrent li and the see console.

```
<h1>
Please first click on input and click on different diffrent li and the see console. 
</h1>
<div class="select_option"  id="select1">
      <input
        type="text"
        name=""
        placeholder="Select here..."
      />
      <ul>
        <li>Level 1</li>
        <li>Level 2</li>
        <li>Level 3</li>
        <li>Level 4</li>
        <li>Level 5</li>
        <li>Level 6</li>
        <li>Level 7</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

> jS

```
Please see JSfiddle link
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wq8La65n/2/

Comment: Your question body is smaller than the question title!!! Please provide more details.

Comment: Please provide more informations (your full code, you're talking about <li>'s but there aren't any in your code example?). But I think what you're looking for is probably "e.stopPropagation()" but I don't know as you haven't provided anything usable so far

Comment: There is no `open_ul('select1')` defined in the code!!!

Comment: @Mamun Please see this link https://jsfiddle.net/wq8La65n/2/

Comment: why do you want attach listener inside onlick function ? shall i know the reason?

Comment: @mariappank Becuase i want to make typehide with custom selectbox

Comment: @PraveenKumar here we don't have any select boxes . what is the select box?  can you explain  what you want exactly

Comment: @PraveenKumar, I just wanted to know whether you have noticed my answer or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with a named function as the event handler function like the following way.

```js
document.querySelector('#select1').onclick = function(e){
  var ul_li = document.querySelectorAll("#select1 ul li");
  ul_li.forEach(function(li_click) {
    li_click.addEventListener("click", clickHandler);
  });
}
function clickHandler(e){
  console.log(e.target.textContent);
}
```

```html
<h1>
Please first click on input and click on different diffrent li and the see console. 
</h1>
<div class="select_option" id="select1">
  <input
    type="text"
    name=""

    placeholder="Select here..."
  />
  <ul>
    <li>Level 1</li>
    <li>Level 2</li>
    <li>Level 3</li>
    <li>Level 4</li>
    <li>Level 5</li>
    <li>Level 6</li>
    <li>Level 7</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what i want. Thanks again.